# how to set field on method save

Tags: django, authentication, profile

I'm doing a profile see my models in django:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=TIPO_U)
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=SEXO)
    datanasc = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, blank=True, null=True)
    ano = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    matricula = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

check out my forms:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Usuário:", required=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Senha:",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True))
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Confirmar Senha:",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True))
    email = forms.EmailField(label="E-mail:", required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="Nome completo:", required=True)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(("Já existe um usuário com esse nome por favor escolha outro."))

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(("A confirmação da senha não confere, verifique."))
        return password2

    class Meta:
      model = UserProfile
      exclude = ('user',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.fields['username'].initial = self.instance.user.username
            self.fields['email'].initial = self.instance.user.email
            self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.instance.user.first_name
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.instance.pk is None):
            u = User.objects.create_user(
                username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
                email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
            u.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
            u.is_active = True
        else:
            u = self.instance.user
            u.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            u.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        u.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']  
        u.save()
        self.user = u
        profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        return profile
```

when running an insert I get the following error:

profile_userprofile.user_id may not be NULL

I do not know if it is correct but I did:
self.user = u

***EDIT***

My error was to forget to put: instance

**self.instance.user = u**

Comment: `self.user` refers to the `user` field in the form which you have excluded and therefore won't be saved when you call super.save. It might be better to move the code in save to your view instead of the form.

Comment: My error was to forget to put: instance

self.instance.user = u

Comment: ah, yes... although IMO there is room for the cleaning up and using more conventional way...

Answer (score 0):

try to replace the last three lines of `save` method w/

```
profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
profile.user = u
profile.save()
return profile
```

Or you could do it outside the `form.save`, ref [the modelforms doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)